# Need To add extra column in junction table created by TypeORM Using Many to many relationship #TypeORM #Nestjs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Need To add extra column in junction table created by TypeORM Using Many to many relationship.

Is it possible to do so..

Please help me into that ASP

#TypeORM #Nestjs

I created custom entity for junction table but it didn't worked for me